# MapKit LocalSearch not working

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapkit

I have made a simple function to perform a local search

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    var localSearchRequest:MKLocalSearchRequest!
    var localSearchResponse:MKLocalSearchResponse!
    localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = locationSearchBar.text
    let localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
    localSearch.start { (localSearchResponse, Error) in
        if localSearchResponse == nil{
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "No Place Found", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "확인", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }
            self.pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            self.pointAnnotation.title = self.locationSearchBar.text
            self.pointAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.latitude, longitude: localSearchResponse!.boundingRegion.center.longitude)


            self.pinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: self.pointAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: nil)
            self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.pointAnnotation.coordinate
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pinAnnotationView.annotation!)



    }
}
```

but it is not working

It goes to "Thread 1 EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" on line `localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = locationSearchBar.text` and it says "No Place Found" everytime I search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you haven't initialized the `localSearchResponse` you have simply declared it.

**Changed line:**

```
var localSearchResponse:MKLocalSearchResponse!
```

**With**

```
var localSearchResponse = MKLocalSearchResponse()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're accessing the wrong search bar object when you call that line. The function takes an argument of `searchBar: UISearchBar`, so you probably meant to use that variable. Change the line with the error to:

`localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBar.text`

Looks like you have a bunch of places in this code so you might just want to change the function argument name.

Comment: well, it doesn't work. It still says unexpectedly found a nil value

Comment: Is your storyboard hooked up properly still after changing the code